# phpMyAdmin is adding extra rows to database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Simple PHP code that writes to and reads from a MySql database. Starting with two rows of data entered manually in phpMyAdmin, then inserting a new row via PHP code, when reading back the database contents, all appears fine (see below).

However, when the database is then checked on phpMyAdmin, the new row has been inserted three times instead of once. Any ideas?

PHP code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "<br>";}
else{
  echo "Connected to MySQL okay <br>";}

// Test inserting new row into database
$str = "INSERT INTO sites (src_name, date, content) VALUES ('BBC', '2016-02-24 08:00:00', 'Bad weather in UK')";
$result = $con->query($str);
if ($result === TRUE){
  echo "New record inserted successfully <br>";}
else{
  echo "Error: ". $con->error . "<br>";}

// Test reading from database
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM sites");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "Source : " . $row["src_name"]. " - Date: " . $row["date"]. " - Content: " . $row["content"]. "<br>";}
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

PHP page output - all looks good:
[image]

phpMyAdmin page - showing the 3 rows:
[image]

Comment: Do you have a primary key on this table?  That would help define where the error is occurring.

Comment: In your `$str` can you add `rand()` appended to one of the values? This can pinpoint either the script being run multiple times or the query running multiple times. Example, `$str = "INSERT INTO sites (src_name, date, content) VALUES ('BBC', '2016-02-24 08:00:00', 'Bad weather in UK " . rand() . "')";`

Comment: One thing is sure: phpmyadmin is **not** inserting extra rows into any table.

Comment: Devon I haven't specifically set a primary key at any point.As Dave Chen suggested, appended the rand() function to $str, and on the PHP page it appends 1423 to the single entry. In phpMyAdmin the 3 entries are now appended with: 1423, 29284, 8178. As each entry in the database is now different, does that mean the PHP query is being called 3 times?

Comment: Adding a primary key to the table (simply created a new column called item_number and made it primary key) as Devon suggested, has solved this problem.